# Android Emulator's "Enable keyboard input" always unchecked after Mac OS Sierra reboot

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, macos-sierra

Since updating the emulator it doesn't remember the "Enable keyboard input" checkbox on system restarts.

[image]

Does anybody have a similar issue or knows how to fix it?

I use:

[image]

Comment: Also happens when you wipe the emulator's data

Comment: Have you logged a bug with google about this?

Comment: no, where would I do this?

Comment: Android Studio -> Help -> Submit Feedback... would be helpful if you commented back here with the link to the resulting issue.

Comment: here is the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65435857

Comment: it's a duplicate of https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64053647

Comment: according to the last link this should be fixed in Android Studio 3.0 stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android Studio 3.0 stable this issue has been fixed for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but seems I fixed it. I removed all virtual devices and then add a new one, reboot the system, open AVD manager and check Keyboard Input checkbox, the value was saved.

**System Info**

Android Studio 2.3.3 and Linux Mint 18.2